# Image comparation libraries for fingerprints

Tags: image, opencv, computer-vision, fingerprint, biometrics

I'm want to develop a server-side application for fingerprint sensor. There will be one database of fingerprints on server and a comparation mechanism. Sensor will send image to the server. I'm looking for some library that can compare source image (from sensor) with images in database. Maybe there are some specific libs that can work with that biometric data? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to develop a distributed system with several scanners and one verificator. Scanners will send image of fingerprint to verificator via IP network. Verificator will compare this image with allowed fingerptins in his database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many libraries to work with many different types of biometric. Depends of what type of biometric you will work.

Most common is fingerprint. If you want a free library you can try [NBIS](http://www.nist.gov/itl/iad/ig/nbis.cfm) from NIST. Therefore if you want a better library you can try Aware or Neurotechnology libraries. And you can talk with vendor of your biometric sensor asking a library. Many biometric devices vendors have free libraries to customer that buy they devices, like Suprema, Crossmatch, Nitgen, Fujitsu, SRI,...

Please elaborate better your question telling us what biometric type you want to work: fingerprint, facial, finger vein, palm vein, DNA, signature, keystrokes, etc...

Comment: I want to develop a distributed system with several scanners and one verificator. Scanners will send image of fingerprint to verificator via IP network. Verificator will compare this image with allowed fingerptins in his database.

Comment: To do this, you will need a 3rd party match library. Because this "free" libraries that suppliers give with its scanners works only with connected scanner. At client side you can use these libraries to collect images, generate templates and send to your server. At server side you will need another fingerprint matcher SDK to compare templates and answer a result. Server side library to this case is a little bit more expensive. You can use NBIS, that is free or buy a commercial one from [Veridis](http://www.veridisbiometrics.com/), Neurotechnology, etc...